# Outlook 2010 strips out ALL inline formatting if I use <style> in head of HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, responsive

I am attempting a responsive html email. It works perfectly on my desktop, on the iphone, but when I test in outlook it strips out large areas of formatting (in outlook only). I am using media queries, but I don't need them to work in outlook. I did a test with the style tags removed and  it worked fine. The problem is the media queries are in the style tags, and it wont be responsive on the iPhone. This happens even if I have empty style tags .

Is there a way to hide styles from outlook only? I tried:

```
     <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
      <style>
 </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

But it still breaks outlook formatting. I'm talking about inline formatting, not the obvious style in the header. Here is the thing though, some of the inline styles work. Weird. weird..

Comment: outlook uses the msword html rendering engine, and that engine could be charitably called "a total festering pile of unflushed public toilets"

Comment: Have you tried using a media query with a min-width for all of your desktop styles that you don't want used in outlook?

Comment: It seems that it is removing all conditional formatting if there is a <style> tag in the header

Comment: If I could use inline media queries I could eliminate the need for a style tag in the header and this would solve the problem. Are inline media queries possible?